# Angular / FireStore - Creating an observable reference to a document with the get method

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

**What I'm Using**

- Angular
- Firestore

**What I'm trying to achieve**

- Live updates
- If data is changed in the database, it automatically updates on the page without navigating between views or reloading the page

**What I've done**

- Originally, I was using AngularFire to display the document as an observable which achieved the live udpates. However, anytime I deleted the document, (through a custom button on the page) an error was thrown in the console to check that the document exists. (Probably because after deleting the document, it's still on the page before re-routing and thinks I'm trying to present a document that isn't there)
- As a result, I used the FireStore documentation to implement the 'get' method so that if I delete a document, the page will check if the document exists. Therefore, my console error was resolved: [enter link description here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md). It does however mean I no longer get the live updates.

**What I would like to do**

- Switching from an observable to a get method has resulted in my data not updating live. Is there a way to achieve this with my code below?
- or is there a way to check if the document exists whilst using the angularfire approach?

**Component.ts**

```js
export class
....

// These two were originally used whilst using the AF observables
 private projectDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;
  project: Observable<any>;

getProjectData() {
    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var docRef = db.collection(`folders/${this.folderId}/albums`).doc(`${this.albumId}`);

    docRef.get().then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        
        // A const for the returned data
        const data = doc.data();

        this.album_title = data.album_title;
        this.album_reference = data.album_reference;

      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: you are not using angularfire2?

Comment: Hey Daule. AngularFire5. I couldn't find anything in the AngularFire5 Firestore documentation that checks for a document existing. The Firestore documentation does. But if I use that, it's no longer an observable. Hopefully I"m missing something.